# Failed to install parallels tools on ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, server, parallels, visualization

I installed Ubuntu 18 using parallels on Mac.

Now I'm trying to install parallels tools and wasn't successful after multiple hours.

When I start the OS I click on "Install Parallels Tools..." and get the following message:

[image]

Plus in parallels settings I have:

[image]

But when I search for the file, nothing is being returned as shown in the first image.

Plus, when I try to inter parallels file I get:

[image]

How can I install the tools?

Comment: kindly update the question, I have no enough points to insert images

Comment: Am I missing something, 23 views and no answer or someone to insert my images...